# Coalesce in duplicated values

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

And I want to transform for each value a column, to become something like this:
[image]

If I do a query like this:

```
Select  "_sdc_source_key_id",
       COALESCE(value='Integrity',null) as cia_security
       
       ,COALESCE (value='Confidentiality',null) as cia_conf
       
       ,COALESCE (value='Availability',null) as cia_availability
      
 FROM
staging_jira.issues__fields__customfield_10420
where _sdc_source_key_id='201496'
```

That is my result, I have duplicated rows:

[image]

What should be the best solution to achieve my transformation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can `group by` source key id, or make use of pivots to acheive the same.

Comment: COALESCE(X, null) is equivalent to COALESCE(X) which is equivalent to just X. What are you trying to do? Post your expected output and tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `GROUP By "_sdc_source_key_id"` and use `MAX` of your values

```
Select  "_sdc_source_key_id",
       MAX(COALESCE(value='Integrity',null)) as cia_security
       
       ,MAX(COALESCE (value='Confidentiality',null)) as cia_conf
       
       ,MSX(COALESCE (value='Availability',null)) as cia_availability          
 FROM
staging_jira.issues__fields__customfield_10420
where _sdc_source_key_id='201496'
GROUP BY "_sdc_source_key_id"
```

If your databse doesn't support MAX from boolean switch to Int

```
Select  "_sdc_source_key_id",
       MAX(CASE WHEN value='Integrity' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as cia_security
       
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN value='Confidentiality' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as cia_conf
       
       ,MSX(CASE WHEN value='Availability' THEN 1 ELSE null END) as cia_availability          
 FROM
staging_jira.issues__fields__customfield_10420
where _sdc_source_key_id='201496'
GROUP BY "_sdc_source_key_id"
```

Comment: Thank you! But in this case max will not work with coalesce because I have the error Max(boolean) does not exists.

Comment: which database are you using? can you also suply a dbfiddle for testing

Comment: you also can switch to integer